# Connecting Microsoft sql server with Django App

Tags: sql-server, django, pycharm

I want to connect the Microsoft SQL server with my Django application. In Microsoft SQL management studio I am creating one database then I am creating Login with a password and then I am creating user using this Login option. In my settings file of Django application, I am providing my database name and user name and password of Login that I have created. I think I am doing something wrong. Whenever I am trying to connect then it is showing user and password credentials in not correct. There is no option of giving the password to the user. While creating Login I am providing a password. I have just started using Microsoft SQL server. In postgres, I use to create one user and database and give privileges of the database to that user then I use to pass credentials in my settings.py of Django app.

I am trying to connect Microsoft SQL server with Django.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': 'ankur_database',
        'USER': 'ankur_user',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server',
            'unicode_results': True,

        },
    }
```

What I should provide in the password and should I provide 'localhost' in HOST. What is the correct way of creating a database in the Microsoft SQL server and creating a user for that Database?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood. Are these credentials work when you connect using a SQL Client?

Comment: @DaniloAkamine Yes, it works perfectly with other databases. Basically, I think I am doing something wrong while making a database in Microsoft SQL server and using its credentials in the django app. I am new to Microsoft SQL server. What is actually password for the user in MSSQL? Is it the same as the Login password.

Comment: Yes, in that case the password for `ankur_user`. The process is gonna be the same that you do in other databases. Create a login with password, give the right permissions you need and configure in Django settings.